# Why are string conversions slowing down my code?

Tags: regex, string, list, substring, counter

I am new to python and wrote and code that:

- Reads a text file.
- Saves in a list.
- Performs regex.
- Converts list to string
- Removes unwanted special characters.
- Puts the stuff back to a list.
- uses a counter on the list and then packs them into a dictionary.
- Finally plotting the keys and values using Pandas.

As you can my Python experience is pretty low. My code works perfect for smaller files but when I use something like a 700 MB file it seems to be running forever!

How can I optimize my code?

Here is my input file format.

```
74M2S
73M
74M2S
*
73M
75M1S
```

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

f = open('/PathTpFile/MyFILE.txt','r+')

listToStr:  str
str2:   str
mylist1 = []

for line in f.readlines():

    mylist1.append([re.findall(r'[\d]+M', line)])    
    mylist1.sort(reverse=True)
    listToStr = ' '.join(map(str, mylist1))

    specialChars = "M[]'"
    for specialChar in specialChars:
        listToStr = listToStr.replace(specialChar, '')

    words: list = listToStr.split()

counts = Counter(words)
dict(counts)
print(counts)

f.close()

keys = counts.keys()
values = counts.values()
print(counts.keys())
print(counts.values())
plt.bar(keys, values)
plt.savefig("out.png")
```

Comment: Why are you wrapping the `findall()` results in another list: `[re.findall(r'[\d]+M', line)]`?

Comment: why use `[\d]+M` instead of `\d+M` ?

Comment: Why do you reassign `words` each time through the loop? Do it once at the end.

Comment: why remove M[] afterwards if you first add then? Why not simply catch only the numbers before the M and skip the 3 replace-steps completely?

Comment: Maybe that's the mistake. Then how can I use it? I want to use the counter on substring list from regex

Comment: You overcomplicated things - what exactly is interesting for you in your files? Only numbers that come before M?

Comment: You're doing LOTS of things every time through the `for line` loop that should just be done at the end.

Comment: Why do you need to sort anything if your goal is just to count the words?

Comment: Can a line have more than one number? If not, you can just use `re.search()` rather than `re.findall()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't read line by line, read the entire file.
2. Use `re.findall()` on the entire file to get all the matching numbers.
3. Use a regexp that just returns the numbers, so you don't need to use `re.sub()` to remove the extra characters. You can use a lookahead to match the `M` without including it in the results.
4. There's no need to sort the words before counting.

```
with open('/PathTpFile/MyFILE.txt','r') as f:
    text: str = f.read()

mylist1: list = re.findall(r'\d+(?=M)', text)
counts: dict = Counter(mylist1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's walk through what this code does, given your example input:

1. It reads the line `74M2S`.

   1. It finds `74M` within that line and puts it in the list.
   2. It sorts the list.
   3. It searches for and removes the `M` from `74M`.
2. It reads the line `73M`.

   1. It finds `73M` and puts it in the list.
   2. It sorts the list.
   3. It searches for and removes the `M` from each of `74M` and `73M`.
3. It reads the line `74M2S`.

   1. It finds `74M` and puts it in the list.
   2. It sorts the list.
   3. It searches for and removes the `M` from each of `74M`, `73M`, and `74M`.
4. It reads the line `*`.

   1. It finds nothing and puts it in the list.
   2. It sorts the list.
   3. It searches for and removes `M` from each of `74M`, `73M`, and `74M`.
5. It reads the line `73M`.

   1. It finds `73M` and puts it in the list.
   2. It sorts the list.
   3. It searches for and removes `M` from each of `74M`, `73M`, `74M`, and `73M`.
6. It reads the line `75M1S`.

   1. It finds `75M` and puts it in the list.
   2. It sorts the list.
   3. It searches for and removes `M` from each of `74M`, `73M`, `74M`, `73M`, and `75M`.

Look at sub-step 3 and how it progresses. Notice that you are repeatedly searching for `M` in strings that have already been searched, over and over and over again. Every line gets redundantly searched for the special characters to remove once for each and every line after it, in addition to when it is first read. If you have a million lines, the first line gets scanned a million times. That is the primary time waster in this code. Scan each line once, and only once, by scanning the individual line, not the entire list.

Sub-step 2 is also pointlessly redundant. If you have a million lines, then you sort an increasingly large fraction of those lines a million times. If sorting even matters at all, it can be done once at the end, when all lines are already in the list.

Answer (score -1):

For big files a linewise approach is ok, but then regex for each single line is overkill. You can check each line if it contains `'M'` and if so, split it and add the first part to a counting dict immerdiately:

```
with open("d.txt","w") as f:
    f.write("""74M2S
73M
74M2S
*
73M
75M1S""")

counts = {}

with open("d.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if "M" in line:
            key = line.split("M")[0]
            counts.setdefault(key,0)
            counts[key] += 1

print(counts.keys())
print(counts.values())
```

You can easily speed this up using a `defaultdict(int)` if `dict.setdefault` slows you down - but this should be plenty fast.

Output:

```
dict_keys(['74', '73', '75'])
dict_values([2, 2, 1])
```